# TimeZoneInfo Id from coordinates

Tags: c#, timezone

I have a list of coordinates in my database, next to which I need to add another column that will contain the Id as listed in TimeZoneInfo class. Do you have any idea on where to get this informations? A public database? A web service? A way to calculate it?

Thanks

Comment: OpenStreetMap has a [`timezone` key](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:timezone) that might be helpful.

Comment: And see also [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824)

Comment: Thanks I found my answer in How to get a time zone from a location? I have choose to use Google TimeZone API. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

I found my answer in How to get a time zone from a location? I have choose to use Google TimeZone API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/.

Thanks again!